# How to get the sql query sorted by Weekday

Tags: sql, postgresql, tablesorter, metabase

I need to get a table in metabase where the rows are correspond to dispatch number while the columns are the day of the week.

the code for my sql is

```
SELECT 
    to_char( date_trunc('day',delivery_date_end) , 'Dy') as week,
    (dispatch_no)::int,
    (COUNT(DISTINCT delivery_id) FILTER (WHERE (date_part('epoch',delivery_date_end)::int >= date_part('epoch',delivered_at)::int)) / COUNT(DISTINCT delivery_id)::float) * 100 AS not_late

FROM sale_b2c
WHERE 
    delivery_date_end IS NOT NULL AND 
    status = 'Delivered' AND 
    delivered_at IS NOT NULL AND 
    {{city}} AND 
    {{delivery_date}} AND
    {{hub}} AND
    dispatch_no IS NOT NULL AND
    dispatch_no !='1.0'

GROUP BY  1,2
ORDER BY 2
```

The output looks something like this after pivoting the table in metabase

```
Dispatch No | Fri | Mon | Sat | Sun | Thu | Tue | Wed |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1           | a1  |  a2 | a3  | a4  | a5  | a6  | a7  |
2           | b1  |  b2 | b3  | b4  | b5  | b6  | b7  |
3           | c1  |  c2 | c3  | c4  | c5  | c6  | c7  | 
4           | d1  |  d2 | d3  | d4  | d5  | d6  | d7  | 
5           | e1  |  e2 | e3  | e4  | e5  | e6  | e7  |
```

I am unable to figure out a way to sort this output in proper order of weekdays.
I tried using

```
ORDER BY 2,1
```

but it always throw error.
It is also not able to use week while trying to ORDER By in some scenarios.

How can I sort my query in proper weekday format?

Comment: Are you sure that you are running MySQL? This does not look like MySQL syntax (could be Postgres).

Comment: Do you want the ORDER of weekdays to be Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri?

Comment: @AlexMaina Yes.

Comment: What is the output you want?

Comment: Just the same output but the weekdays sorted like Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat , Sun @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: `order by extract(dow from delivery_date_end)`?

Comment: It might be postgres. I was just assigned a task , but the editor shows sql editor. @GMB

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It didn't work . The error thrown is 

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "sale_b2c.delivery_date_end" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 801`
Also the delivery_date_end is in Friday, April 12, 2019 12:30 PM format

Answer (score 1):

Why not pivot the data in Postgres?

```
SELECT dispatch_no,
       MAX(not_late) FILTER (WHERE week = 'Mon') as mon,
       MAX(not_late) FILTER (WHERE week = 'Tue') as tue,
       MAX(not_late) FILTER (WHERE week = 'Wed') as wed,
       MAX(not_late) FILTER (WHERE week = 'Thu') as thu,
       MAX(not_late) FILTER (WHERE week = 'Fri') as fri,
       MAX(not_late) FILTER (WHERE week = 'Sat') as sat,
       MAX(not_late) FILTER (WHERE week = 'Sun') as sun
FROM (SELECT to_char( date_trunc('day',delivery_date_end) , 'Dy') as week,
             (dispatch_no)::int,
             (COUNT(DISTINCT delivery_id) FILTER (WHERE (date_part('epoch',delivery_date_end)::int >= date_part('epoch',delivered_at)::int)) / COUNT(DISTINCT delivery_id)::float) * 100 AS not_late    
      FROM sale_b2c
      WHERE delivery_date_end IS NOT NULL AND 
            status = 'Delivered' AND 
            delivered_at IS NOT NULL AND 
            {{city}} AND 
            {{delivery_date}} AND
            {{hub}} AND
            dispatch_no IS NOT NULL AND
            dispatch_no <> '1.0'
      GROUP BY 1,2
     ) w
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: It didn't work @Gordon. the table's column becomes the percentage values. Which should be the values in each cell.
Running your code filled the table with null values